# Select counts from same column based on different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of tables that look like this

```
Table1
Name varchar
ID int

Table2
ID int
Run_Date datetime
```

I am trying to select the name in one column, and then a count of the dates into 2 columns.  1 column would be all dates per name from last week and the second column would be all counts per name from this week.  The results would look like something like this

So if my tables looked like this

```
Table1
Name1    1
Name2    2
Name3    3

Table2
1   2016-11-21 8:40:23.570
2   2016-11-21 8:50:23.570
1   2016-11-21 9:40:23.570
1   2016-11-21 10:40:23.570
1   2016-11-16 10:40:23.570
2   2016-11-16 10:40:23.570
3   2016-11-21 8:40:23.570
```

My results would look something like

```
Name      This_Week      Last_week
Name1        3               1
Name2        1               1
Name3        1               0
```

I can get the values separately by doing

```
WHERE DATEPART(wk, Run_Date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(yy, Run_Date) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())
```

I just add a -1 after the week to get everything from last week.  How can I get these to show up side by side in the same table?

I have tried doing a CASE

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Run_DATE) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(yy, Run_Date) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS This_Week
```

But it looks like it just counts all dates in database for all Names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Run_DATE) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(yy, Run_Date) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS This_Week
```

Take out the `ELSE 0`.

`COUNT` will ignore `NULLs` but `ELSE 0` will assign a value.  taking it out altogether will mean it won't count the `ELSE` side of the statement.

Comment: Sigh.  I should have seen that.  Thanks Matt

Comment: no problem its easy to overlook done it myself a couple of times I am sure.  the other way to fix would have been to change it to SUM(...) and leave the case statement as you had it.  Count is nice though for instance if you want to count DISTINCT ids, dates, etc where as with SUM you cannot accomplish that